# checking the value of a variable if it returns a 'value' or returns [object]

Tags: javascript, object, adodb

How can I check that the variable that I am setting will either be a value or if it will just return [object]

```
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_imts WHERE [File Number] = '" + filenumber + "'"

cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + dbPath + dbFile + "")

var rec = cn.Execute(mySQL)

alert(rec(0))
```

so, the following will result as the above, if the filenumber already exists in the database then rec(0) will return the first field value, and so on.

my dilemma is that if the filenumber was not found in the database then rec(0) returns [object]

how can I create if statement to catch the [object] then alert("empty") and if the rec(0) returns a value, then alert("not empty")

Comment: `if (typeof rec(0) === "object") { alert("empty"); }` (just a guess based on the information you've presented).

Comment: The above returns empty no matter what, if the record exists or not.

Comment: What does the documentation say? I've not coded DB access from JavaScript, but I would expect a function called `Execute()` to return a recordset object of some kind, and for that recordset to have a property something like `rec.EOF` to tell you whether you're at the end of the set or not, so testing that property would tell you whether any rows were returned.

Comment: I am playing around with the concept of not even opening a recordset, I was trying to see if I can simply catch the [object] somehow when it doesnt equal to anything.